# Как изменить год, месяц и день в DateTime C#

Tags: wpf, datetime, выпадающий-список

Не могу разобраться с get и set(если всё дело конечно в этом). Проблема с последней строкой в этой части программы. Выдает ошибку CS0200 - "Невозможно присвоить значение свойству или индексатору "DateTime.Year" - доступ только для чтения"

Пытаюсь присвоить значения, выбранные в выпадающем списке.

Само задание звучит так:

Разработайте и реализуйте приложение WPF, которое:

- содержит три выпадающих списка, с помощью которых можно выбрать год, месяц и день
- количество дней в месяце определяется только после выбора года и месяца, до этого, выпадающий список с выбором дня должен быть не активен
- после выбора всех трёх параметров, должно появляться сообщение с информацией о том, сколько лет, месяцев и дней прошло с выбранной даты до текущего момента

```
    namespace lab4
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        string a, b, c;
        string aa, bb, cc;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now; 

        DateTime dt { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Year_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            a = Year.Text;
            DateTime dt = new DateTime();
            dt.ToString();
            
            dt.Year = a;
```

Comment: `DateTime` -- неизменяемый класс, его свойства нельзя менять, можно только создать новый объект `dt = new DateTime(year, month, day)`, где `year, month, day` - целые числа.

Comment: @Nowhere Man Разобралась, спасибо!